# REST api running in server gives error msg

Tags: php, rest, api

I followed this website to create my own REST api [https://www.phpflow.com/php/create-php-restful-api-without-rest-framework-dependency/][1]

My rest Api is running in my remote server 207.43.8.220:8008. these are my php files I put them under var/www/api.
the connection.php is under var/www/api

```
 <?php
Class dbObj{
/* Database connection start */
var $servername = "207.43.8.220:8008";
var $username = "root";
var $password = "qwerty";
var $dbname = "UsersApp";
var $conn;
function getConnstring() {
    $con = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } else {
        $this->conn = $con;
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
}
?>
```

these files (.htaccess and users.php) are under var/www/api/v1
users.php file:

```
// Connect to database
include("../connection.php");
$db = new dbObj();
$connection =  $db->getConnstring();

$request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
switch($request_method)
{
    case 'GET':
        // Retrive Products
        if(!empty($_GET["id"]))
        {
            $id=intval($_GET["id"]);
            get_users($id);
        }
        else
        {
            get_users();
        }
        break;
    default:
        // Invalid Request Method
        header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
        break;
}
function get_users()
{
    global $connection;
    $query="SELECT * FROM users";
    $response=array();
    $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $response[]=$row;
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

when I run 207.43.8.220:8008/api/v1/users I get my users.php code lignes not the result with 200ok msg. when I add `<?php` to users.php I get 500 internal server error with an empty page. I don't know where is the problem? Normally I should get the result in json format.

NB: I didn't create an index.php file I juste created .htaccess. My rest api will be used by android mobile application.

while looking at the error.log file I found that the problem is caused by declaring the same method get_users(). I commented one of these functions and I get the result. Now I want to know how to use the both methods but with different input like it is mentioned in the code.

Comment: Look in the error log, if you have an 500 Error you see more information in the log

Comment: #Spirit thank you for your response it solves my problem. I didn't know that there is such file and I passed 6h trying to solve it. The problem was in declaring two functions with the same name, and another problem I figured it by myself was the servername address should be without the port number